# Optimize over theta or theta and beta in logistic mixed model (nagq = 0 vs nagq = 1)

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I've been reading about item response model guides for R and my model is :

```
mod <- glmer(response ~ 0 + item + (1|house_id), 
              family = binomial, nAGQ = 0)
```

and I want to investigate the random effects (which will be used as indices to compare the houses in the model above) using:

```
ranef(mod)["(Intercept)"]
```

I used bootstrap = 1000 for my model and obtained the CIs. However, without nAGQ = 0, it'll take 2 hours for my computer to process this. When nAGQ = 0 was activated, it took me 2 minutes. Some guides/opinion out there been saying that n = 0 only integrates over theta, while nAGQ = 1 integrate over theta and beta. Also, nAGQ = 0 claimed to be less accurate, but I think the bootstrapping process re-increase the power of the statistical inference of this model relates to its random effects.

I'm suspecting that this relates to coefficient like Y = B0 + B1X but I might be wrong. Does this referring to random and fixed effects and if I'm only interested for the random effects, does using nAGQ = 0 affect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimation of mixed-effects logistic regression requires numerically integrating the random effects to calculate the likelihood of the model. There are several approaches to do this and you can find more information in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436611/how-are-pql-reml-ml-laplace-gauss-hermite-related-to-each-other/436711#436711).

In general, and even though setting nAGQ much greater than 1 takes more time, it is to be preferred. This will ensure that the error in the approximation of the likelihood function is minimized.

Comment: If I incoporate nAGQ  = 0 with bootstrap to estimate the random effect coefficients, I think it'll produce a "conservative" estimate as the error in the approximation is bigger. However, I haven't seen (from online sources and the link) anything that says nAGQ = 0 makes our estimates biased, therefore a model with nAGQ = 0 is still valid, isn't it? Do you think comparing bootsrapped coefficients of two nAGQ = 0 model is valid as well given that they operates in the same premise (all same variables but different data)?

Comment: @user282983 nAGQ = 0 is less accurate than nAGQ >= 1, and using the Bootstrap will not alleviate the problem. I.e., the estimates are expected to be more biased with this option.

Comment: Final follow up question: If I'm comparing two models with both nAGQ = 0 (i.e model1 : response ~ var1, var2, var3, and model2: response ~ var4, var5, var6 and then compare their random effects, will it be valid? Since the two models are both biased, and the only difference between them is the set of predictors

Comment: @user282983 The comparison will not be trustworthy.